# File permissions on files and directories added via ftp

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, permissions, ftp, debian-wheezy

I have recently bought a raspberry pi that I have installed as an Apache web server.

I do however have one problem: When I add files via ftp the permissions are set to `-rw-------`. There for I can not access the files without changing their permissions manually first, e.g `chmod 755 /var/www -R` (everytime I add a file or directory via ftp that is).

But this is of course not the correct way. What am I missing out?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I am running vsftpd and Apache2 on a Debian "Wheezy", and followed this guide pretty much.

Edit #2:
Requested umask settings from /etc/vsftpd.conf file:

> # Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
>   
>   # if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
>   
>   #local_umask=022

Comment: Server Fault is for Professional System Administrators only. Developer and Hobbyist questions are Off Topic. Please see the [FAQ] for more details. Your question would be on-topic on [unix.se] however.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Forgot to read FAQ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you paste your `umask` settings of your FTP server's configuration file here?

For a VSFTPD server, it will be like this:

`local_umask=022`

umask `022` means the permission `755`

umask `002` means the permission `775`

FYI : Using umask, in Linux, we can decide the default permissions for a file/directory.

You may find more details regarding umask and how it's used in these two articles;

[Umask value usage](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

[Define umask](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/umask-define-linuxunix.html)

Comment: Where do I find the umask settings?

Comment: If your FTP server is vsftpd, then configuration file will be `/etc/vsftpd.conf` by default.

Comment: @Lindhe94 as he mentioned, it depends on which ftp server you are using.  What FTP server did you install?  Or are you actually using _sftp_?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is vsftpd I am using. Found the file. Just a minute and I'll paste the umask in my first post.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand!
As you can see from what I pasted into my first post the umask is by default 077 (which I suppose mean -rw-------, since this is what I get?), but if I uncomment the last line it will change to 022, which is, as you mentioned, 755!
Did I get it? :)